# Is Krav Maga a hybrid martial art?

Tags: training, mixed-martial-arts, krav-maga

I red that Krav Maga is a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_martial_arts) of other martial arts. If so which are the Martial Art forms that were combined to form Krav Maga?

Comment: Did you read the  [wikipedia page on Krav Maga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krav_Maga) or the [a history](http://www.kravmagainc.com/Imi-Lichtenfeld-History.html)? This question shows no prior research whatsoever.

Comment: I presume, that it is a "push" question. With all respect, I haven't see any other themes here bobbling up with such frequency and "spoilering". One of examples: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/best-way-to-control-a-gun-holder-from-his-back . And all questions of that user: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/6686/deathtoxic . I don't think, that something solid is in need of such advertising.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It is a mixture of Western boxing punches, Karate kicks and knees, Greco-Roman wrestling, Brazilian Jiu-jitsu ground fighting, Jiu-jitsu throws and grappling, Judo, Aikido and most importantly, “bursting,” adapted from Wing Chun.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krav_Maga

Answer (score 4):

Krav Maga is not a martial art. It is a self defense system that has acquired or adapted techniques from different martial arts to fulfill a specific purpose.
Those include groundfighting, stand-up fighting and weapon techniques — one can argue form which art actually ex. BJJ, Muay Thai whatever — but always striving to have the most effective one for the current situation for the needed distance, even modified if needed like the vertical punch (with burst).

Comment: I'd debate your definition of "martial art" not applying, but otherwise, it's a decent answer.

Comment: I second Sean. Imo, all martial arts are "*self defense systems that have acquired or adapted techniques from different [sources] to fulfill a specific purpose.*"

Comment: If you see using pepperspray, a chair, glas or even keys and money as a Martial Art then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Krav Maga is a hybrid of jujitsu, boxing and wrestling because Imi Lichtenfeld, a Hungarian Jew, was a boxer, wrestler and a blackbelt in jujitsu.
He mixed all three martial arts together to create his own personal style krav maga which is Hebrew for contact combat. He went to Israel where he became a soldier and a police officer and taught krav maga to the IDF and Mossad.