# Best way to control a gun holder from his back

Tags: self-defense, krav-maga

An assailant with a gun is threatening someone from a distance. You are behind the assailant. What is the best way to use Krav Maga techniques to control and disarm him so that he won't harm you and his intended target? I would appreciate it if you could add videos.

Comment: The way the question is written, the answers are likely to be subjective and opinion-based. If you changed the question to something like "what techniques could be used" and add more context to the question (e.g. assailant is male, 180 cm, 100 kg, holding a pistol), the answers _may_ be less subjective.

Comment: Yeah, this is a hard one to answer. It's just going to invite a lot of responses like, "Well you could do this thing that I like..." It's subjective. Taking away guns from assailants is not something most martial arts teach, and most aren't going to teach it realistically. Even Krav Maga doesn't particularly like the topic and would instead prefer people use guns against guns. Good luck trying to creep up on someone with a gun and use an Aikido-like wrist throw to take him down and disarm him. What if he hears you first? Bang. You're dead. This is highly dependent on the circumstances.

Comment: This is not really answerable in its current form. You give no information about the actual distances between you, the attacker, the intended victim, the environment, your skill set, etc. As others have said, this will be a lot if "Well, in situation X I'd do Y unless he was Z then I'd do Q..." and so on.

Comment: Go watch a Steven Seagal movie. I'm sure he has some sweet Aikido wrist lock throws to help you disarm the next terrorist hostage situation you stumble upon. Voted to close for reason: Nonsense.

Comment: If the question were changed to "what are ways Krav Maga teaches [for this scenario]", rather than what's the best way, it would be a lot less subjective.  Avi's answer provides two videos that show Krav Maga techniques for the scenario, it's just arguable whether they're the "best".  Getting a list of options and critiques (pros and cons) is more productive than asking for an outright "best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the commenters.
I can offer the following solutions: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LU4uOjsr81g) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqgSaopbTvo) for the required scenario. The principles as shown consist of side step to the shooting hand. Lowering your body and coming as close as possible to the assailant body. Then catching the gun (depends on the gun size) by both hands for full control of the hand. Afterwards release of the gun and full control of the assailant by hitting while the releasing the gun.

Comment: Video #1: Unrealistic. Assumes attacker can't see you from the corner of his eye or hear you creeping up. The concept of grabbing a pistol and twisting it to release the hold on the gun is okay. But it doesn't work on a struggling opponent who can simply pull his hand away from you as you go to grab it, which is what will happen in real life. Once that happens, it's easy and quick for him to re-aim it at you and fire. You have not controlled his body and arm. You have deliberately put yourself in danger by trying to creep up and grab his hand from a visible approach.

Comment: Video #2: Similar issues as video #1. It assumes you can creep up on someone. It assumes he can't see you out of the corner of his eye as you go to reach for the gun. And you haven't controlled his arm or body, putting you at greater risk if he is able to avoid your grasp, re-aim it at you, and fire. The mechanical concept of twisting the gun in such a way as to cause the guy to release it is fine, however.

Comment: I know Krav Maga tries to give you something that works with your instincts and is simple for beginners to remember and do. That's fine. These can work, but with lots of risk. It's just that I think if you want to improve the risk factor, you'll have to come up with a different strategy, and it will require more advanced skill at being able to control someone with grappling. Once you have that control, then you can utilize the main concept of working the gun against the grip of your opponent. My opinion anyway.

Comment: Both videos are fabulous play fighting that will get you killed in real life.

Comment: Why, once you have control of it, would you release the weapon? By all means don't use it, but if you release control there are 2 out of 3 scenarios where it gets used against you again.

Comment: To some extent, I don't think it matters what we think of the techniques shown in the videos - Avi has shown two Krav Maga instructors illustrating very similar technique - it's useful to have the technique listed in an answer.  The question is tagged Krav Maga, which I'd take as lessening the relevance of how other martial arts might improve on Krav Maga's approach.